# Custom Loop for custom post type. Compare by meta_value?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy, functions

I'm a bit confused. I have a custom-post-type named `wr_event`.
I'm using the code underneath to loop through all "upcoming" events (defined by the meta_key `event_date).

The problem I have now is that I want not only to show all upcoming posts, but all posts of the current year.

```
if ( have_posts() ): the_post();

    $current_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y'));
    //$last_year = mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, date('Y') - 1);

    // Show all upcoming events of the current year
    /*$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wr_event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DSC',
        'meta_value' => $current_year,
        'meta_compare' => '>',
        'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
        'term' => get_queried_object()->slug
    );*/

    // Show all upcoming and taken place events of the current year
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'wr_event',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        /*'meta_key' => 'event_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'DSC',
        'meta_value' => $last_year,
        'meta_compare' => '>',*/
        'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
        'term' => get_queried_object()->slug
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'inc/event', 'item' );
    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    else: ?>

    <p class="wrapper no-items">
            There are no posts found
        </p>
```

Any idea how to do so? I simply want to list all events filterd by the current taxonomy-term of the current_year. And I can't seem to find out how to do so?

**UPDATE**

Thank you … but how would this look?

```
 $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'wr_event',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'meta_query' => array( array(
                    'key' => 'event_date',
                    'value' => $current_year,
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'type' => 'numeric'
                ) ),
                'taxonomy' => 'event_type',
                'term' => get_queried_object()->slug
            );
```

Comment: How is `event_date` stored? What does the value look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what you've tried (in your commented code), I think you're close. I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that your `event_date` meta field is not stored as a numeric timestamp, which is what you were comparing against. Assuming it is stored as a text date like '2012-12-08' (and if not, it probably should be), here's what you should add to your `$args` array:

```
'meta_query' => array( array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => date( 'Y-m-d', $current_year ),
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'date'
) )
```

## Edit:

Knowing now that your data is stored as a **numeric unix timestamp**, try this:

```
'meta_query' => array( array(
    'key' => 'event_date',
    'value' => $current_year,
    'compare' => '>=',
    'type' => 'numeric'
) )
```

*Note: old answer left in for future readers who may be storing their date as a string.

Comment: Well, thank you. My `event_date` is stored as timestamp. However either way I don't get ANY results from this loop. There are no posts returned. I'm always inside the "else" statement. As if there were no posts. `There are no posts found` <- see my little update above.

Comment: @mathiregister thanks for clarifying. I adjusted my answer to give you something else to try. If that doesn't work, I would install the [Debug Bar plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) and look at the SQL that the page is generating. Then try running that SQL query in MySQL directly. If you're getting results there, it's a **template issue**. If you're not getting results there, post the SQL query and I or someone else can see where things are going wrong.

Comment: Thank you, however still no luck. Again no posts are returned. See my update above. Is this the right way I'm using this `meta_query`? I'll try the Debug Bar plugin tomorrow. Thank you in the meantime. Please make sure to check back here :)

Comment: I would also try removing the 'taxonomy' and 'term' parameters for now. Limit your variables to find the source.